# Is it possible to install Linux packages on OS X?

Tags: macos, package-management

I know that the Mac commandline is very similar to that of Linux operating systems, so it would be nice to use some features of Linux in my Mac, specially installing Linux packages. For example, in Linux we can install a package by simply typing `sudo apt-get install "package name"` at the prompt. Is it possible to do something like this on Mac?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to install and run a variety of UNIX applications on OS X. There are a few solutions out there, my choice and recommendation is [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). I've found other solutions to be overly complex and unwieldy.

Comment: in linux terminal installing command does any thing automatically it downloads files and ... how about Homebrew? is it required to download files manually?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @peaceman once you've [set up Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation), it downloads all the dependencies and files you need for any package you install from its repository. It's a beautiful thing, really.

Comment: How is MacPorts (to pick one) "overly complex and unwieldy"? I installed it and I call `sudo port install "name"` to install something. How is Homebrew easier than that?

Comment: @CajunLuke for one MacPorts will install duplicates of everything it needs. Don't want another bzip2? Too bad, you're getting one. Brew on the other hand leverages the existing system. I have 23 packages I like to install. With Macports that balloons with dependancies to 144 packages. With Homebrew, only 44. That's what I call "overly complex". You should seriously try Homebrew. You'll like it better.

Comment: @bahamat Seeing as I didn't notice the extra packages being installed, I probably wouldn't notice any benefit. I mostly use MacPorts for screwing around (case in point: the last time I touched any MacPorts stuff was to install wine so I could see how well [or how poorly] iTunes for Windows ran on the Mac).

Comment: Like I said, you should seriously try it. It's easier to manage, it's easier to use, it's easier to fix and it's easier to contribute. I'm not trying to win. Just see for yourself, then pick the one you prefer.

Comment: One reasonm I use macports is that it installs its own versions of tools it need like bzip2. This is from 30 years on Unix experience you need to exactly control the versions of things you use and the vendor can't be relied on (see guix for modern setups of Linux to produce even more control).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the open-source package ecosystem has expanded over the lifetime of macOS (neé Mac OS X). There are three main ones:

- [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) is the most active and stable, and should be your first choice for common libraries and apps. (It's based on community-maintained recipes written in Ruby.)
- [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) is a long-lived and also popular system. It tends support a greater variety of systems (old and new) as well as software versions. MacPorts recipes are written in Tcl.
- [Fink](https://www.finkproject.org) is one of the oldest mac package managers and tries to emulate `apt-get`. I don't know anyone personally who's used Fink in the last decade.

Finally, if you're looking for a more experimental and configurable package manager primarily aimed at developing scientific software, [Spack](https://github.com/spack/spack) is a great option. (Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer of the project.)

Comment: You can add pkgsrc and nix

Comment: How is Homebrew more stable than macports?

Comment: FWIW, I used Fink back when it was the only option; it worked OK for a while, but sometimes the dependencies would get tangled up; after one Mac OS X upgrade it got so bad I couldn't fix it, and ended up junking it.  More recently I've been using Homebrew, which has Just Worked with not the slightest trouble.

Comment: Are pkgsrc and nix also viable as mentioned in @mmmmmm 's comment?

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)?